# Regarding definition of Kobayashi length

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

I am totally new in the area of complex geometry. I have been reading this paper by Steven Krantz [The Carath ́eodory and Kobayashi Metrics
and Applications in Complex
Analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608772.pdf). In the definition of the Kobayashi length (Section 3)(Please find screenshot), I have the following doubts:[image]

1) *Fix a point $P \in \Omega$ and a vector $\xi$ which is thought of as being tangent to the plane at the point $P$*

They haven’t mentioned any particular plane in the paper since the beginning so should I assume its the complex plane? What does $\xi$ bieng tangent to the plane at $P$ mean?

2) *We define the infinitesimal Kobayashi or Kobayashi/Royden length of $\xi$ at $P$ to be*

What is the significance of the word infinitesimal here. And is the length of $\xi$ measured from the origin to the point $P$?

Comment: 1. "Plane" is the complex plane $C$ to which $\Omega$ belongs. 2. "Infinitesimal Kobayashi" = "Kobayashi/Royden"$\neq$ "Kobayashi" (this is not the definition of Kobayashi metric (which is given later) but a preliminary one.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko So what exactly is the meaning of $\xi$ bieng tangent to the complex plane as $\xi\in\Omega$? How would you explain this setting to someone who only has a background in complex analysis. Am I supposed to have a differential geometry background too?

Comment: At least you have to look for a definition of the tangent vector (on the first pages of any geometry or multivariate analysis book).

Answer (score 1):

The vector $\xi$ is tangent to the complex line spanned by $\xi$. The significance of "infinitesimal" is that this definition defines a length of a tangent vector (in the sense of differential geometry), which is thought of traditionally as a point infinitesimally near to $P$. There is another definition, which you should find in the same book, of a metric, which will actually give distances between points of $\Omega$ (at least, say, for any bounded domain $\Omega$ in complex Euclidean space). The length is not measured from the origin to $P$, but from the origin of $T_P \Omega$ to $\xi$, i.e. it is the length of a tangent vector, similar to how one measures lengths of tangent vectors in a Riemannian metric. More precisely, the infinitesimal Kobayashi length is a seminorm on each tangent space. It might help to free your intuition if you forget that $\Omega$ is a domain in a complex vector space, and define the infinitesimal Kobayashi length on any complex manifold $\Omega$. There is no reason why $\Omega$ should contain any origin, or have a meaningful notion of distance from any origin.